# win server 2008r2 network share error element not found

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, share

I have setup a Windows Server 2008R2 with DNS and AD.  When I define a shared folder on the Server and connect to it via \domain.lan\folder I can see the content but if I try to change something in the folder I get the error "element not found". This behaviour is always the same. It doesn't matter if I try connecting directly from the server or through a windows 7 client. BUT: IF I ACCESS THE FOLDER VIA IP ADDRESS OF THE SERVER e.g. \192.168.0.22\folder all works fine. So my guess there is a big problem with the Windows DNS Server. Pinging domain.lan results in the correct IP Address so it is resolved correctly. I don't know where the problem can be.

BTW: I could reproduce this problem exactly with Virtual Machines on my PC and different names and IP Addresses...

Does anybody have a guess?

Comment: To access the share i would use `\\server.domain.lan\folder`

Comment: Okey and domain.lan does really not work anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Domain-based DFS namespace`.

Domain-based DFS namespace allows you to use the domain name to access shared folders : `\\domain.lan\folder`

Then, you can grant access (or not) and setup appropriate permissions to Users/Groups on your DFS based shared folders.

Traditional shares are associated with a single server, so you will have to specify the target computer in your SMB path : `\\server.domain.lan\folder`

`DFS` is, IMHO, the most improved way to publish shared folders in Active Directory mainly because it provides more flexibily, scalability, security ([review some benefits here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962138.aspx)).

Appart the fact that i would suggest you to setup `Domain-based DFS namespace` to solve your issue, i would also suggest some further reading :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)
- http://www.maxi-pedia.com/difference+between+shared+folder+and+DFS+root
- http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+DFS
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863.aspx

Hope it helps.